# Mounting Drives after removing windows 8.1 and installing Linuxmint Cinnamon

Tags: windows-8.1, mount, linux-mint, cinnamon

i recently removed windows 8.1 and installed Linux mint 18.1 and i can't access one of my drives which weren't even the ones with windows OS but had Linux mint 17; when i try mounting with terminal i get the message 'no mount point', how can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory to use as a mount point, then mount the disk there.

```
mkdir ~/mint17/
sudo mount /dev/sdX ~/mint17/
```

...where `/dev/sdX` is the device name of the disk you want to mount.